# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE gets stuck

Tags: mysql, jdbc, vert.x

I'm trying to upload a really small file (2 lines) to Google cloud's MySQL (version | 5.7.25-google-log) using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.
The upload is done from another server running in GC (Debian10), the app is a vertx container using latest vertx-mysql-client.
Once started I can see the following in the MySQL processes log:

```
> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id     | User | Host               | db    | Command | Time | State                 | Info                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+--------+------+--------------------+-------+---------+------+-----------------------+------------------
| 223379 | abc  | 10.x.x.3:47542   | mydb   | Query   |   78 | Receiving from client | LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/abc/1592381548212.csv' INTO TABLE ABC FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES (@var1, @var2, @var3) SET CreationDate=@var1, CustomerId=@var2, Type=@var3 |
```

After 90 sec this process entry disappears from the log, no entries are present in the table, the client is still stuck and isn't releasing a connection back to the pool.
It worth noticing that simple SELECT and INSERT queries work as expected.
Any hints what can cause such a behavior?

Comment: How are you checking the logs? Could you check them in Stack driver monitoring link `https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=<PROJECT_ID>&minLogLevel=0&expandAll=false&customFacets=&limitCustomFacetWidth=true&interval=PT1H&resource=cloudsql_database%2Fdatabase_id%2F<PROJECT_ID>%253A<INSTANCE_ID> ` as there the logs doesn't dissapear.

Comment: @atarno might not be supported yet. Can you please [file an issue](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client/issues/new?assignees=&labels=enhancement&template=feature_request.md&title=)?

Comment: @tsegismont i posted in the forum https://groups.google.com/forum/?oldui=1#!topic/vertx/wAkxOV9aKkw  since it works on a different environment i don't know if this is a vertx issue or a gc issue. gave more info there though. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug and has been fixed in https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client/issues/688